# JSONB Index using GIN doesn't work on postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I created index for jsonb column on postgresql, but it seems that index doesn't work when I analyzed by explain command.

Here's my command to add index.

```
CREATE INDEX event_data_idx on json_tbl USING gin(data jsonb_path_ops);
```

Here's explain code.

```
explain select * from json_tbl where data @> '{"type": "good"}'
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                            |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=484) |
| Filter: (data @> '{"type": "good"}'::jsonb)           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN
```

Maybe index doesn't work. Is there wrong point on my index command?
Current psql version is `9.4.1`

Thanks.

Comment: rows=1, what would be the point to use an index when a sequential scan is just as fast? On an (almost) empty table, the query planner won't use an index, unless you disable sequential scans: SET enable_seqscan TO off;

Comment: This is a just table schema for test. I'm curious about why jsonb index doesn't work on this command, not meanings of creating index. Thanks.

Comment: Doing a performance test with just a single row doesn't make sense. The database will never use an index for something like that.

Comment: Ah, I see. When I tested on multiple row, I confirmed index works now. Sorry for that. Thanks.